# What is the correct way to implement Aggregation in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, aggregation

**Context:**

It is common that a situation arise in which I require aggregation: An object make use of another object without owning it. That is, some main module will create and share an object for/to others.

However, I did not found, up to now, a correct way to implement it.

**Previous research:**

1) C-like pointers:
The shared object is provided as a pointer. The problem is that it is up to the programmer to manage correctly the order of creation, sharing and deletion, which could easily carry dangling pointers.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

2) Weak pointers:
Using a shared/weak pointer solve the problem of dangling pointers. The main problem is: it avoid stack objects to be used. It also relay on exceptions which in the best case is a polemic topic, in the worst case is just not possible (kernel/low-level code).

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A());
    std::weak_ptr<A> wa = a; // optional, but required to show the weak_ptr use
    B b(wa);
}
```

3) Shared pointers:
Using only shared pointer has the same problem than (2), but additionally the ownership of A is unknown: that break several design guidelines.

4) Object reference:
Sharing a reference to the object solve dangling issue, and is probably the simplest solution. On the other hand, it force the aggregated object to be passed in the constructor, it avoid assignment operators, and in general limit the design.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B( a );
}
```

5) Never aggregate, just pass as argument.
Even if possible, this increase drastically the number of parameters to some functions. It is, in my opinion, too much additional complexity.

6) Singleton pattern
Singleton allows to access a single object from several modules. But, this only allows one instance to be shared, and it goes against several design guide-lines.

**Question:**

What is the correct way to implement aggregation in modern C++?

Ideal goals would be:

- Make easy to maintain the code, and avoid errors.
- Flexibility to use it in different ways (e.g. stack/heap)
- Not too much additional complexity or obscure code.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer the question. It depends on more architectural considerations than you have shared. These are all valid options depending on other things, though in "modern" c++ you'd prefer not to use raw pointers if possible (and also there is no need to use `new` in most cases either)

Comment: There is no One True Answer.  Pick the best design to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Why does B not own A? Do you have a custom garbage collector to reclaim the heap? Does B outlive A?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with raw pointers being passed and held by modules which know, by their semantics, that they don't own and will never own the object they're passed _as long as the lifetime of the object they're passed exceeds their own_.   And in many use cases, that's known to be true, esp. with regard to modeling aggregation.  If it isn't true then shared_ptr or weak_ptr is used, depending on whether you want to extend the aggregated objects lifetime or not.  BTW, w.r.t. #5, sharing a reference _does not_ solve the dangling issue.

Comment: @davidbak A problem there is that the ownership is unclear from the type.  Hence the proposal for `non_owning_ptr<T>` (the worlds dumbest smart pointer) which makes the lack of ownership clear.

Comment: @vegi: with B not own A, I mean B is not responsible of creating or destroying A. It just get access to it. (the main difference between composition and aggregation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many of the commenters have noted, there's no one solution to your problem.  However, this sort of thing has been discussed in length by people who think about C++ design patterns for a living.  For one great discussion on better handling of dangling pointers (including the suggestion of one of the commenters, `template <class T> using non_owning_ptr<T> = T*`), I suggest Bjarne Stroustrup's [talk](https://youtu.be/1OEu9C51K2A?t=24m19s) on C++ core rules and guidelines, particularly the segment starting with the link given.  Herb Sutter's follow-up [talk](https://youtu.be/hEx5DNLWGgA) is also useful in this regard, introducing some ideas on static analysis tools to enforce these rules.

I know this isn't the magical solution you're looking for, but for what it's worth, it seems to be the solution that people *way* smarter and *way* more experienced with C++ than I am have come up with.  I honestly thing this is the reason Bjarne Stroustrup has spent most of his time recently on these rules and guidelines: perfect solutions to these sorts of things don't exist in C++ itself, but with some constraints, we can come much closer.

Answer (score 2):

> I require aggregation: An object make use of another object without owning it.

That's not any definition of "aggregation" that I'm familiar with. But for the purposes of this post, I'll use it.

There is no way to express the ability of one object to access an object without owning it in the C++ type system. There are simply too many ways to implement this relationship for a type to express this idea.

Let's say that we have some instance A which has access to an instance B but does not own B. So, how do you define the relationship between these two instances? This relationship is not safe if B is destroyed without informing A first. So, how do we ensure that?

There are literally dozens of ways. Maybe B is held in a `shared_ptr` and thus A could hold its reference in a `weak_ptr`, thus becoming informed when B no longer exists. Maybe there is some specific object C that owns both A and B and will ensure this. Maybe the general structure of the code makes it impossible for B to be destroyed before A. Maybe B itself knows when it gets linked to A and will inform A in its destructor. Or maybe the code is fragile, but every person writing the code takes great care to make sure that A doesn't outlive B.

There is no single "correct way to implement it", because "it" is not one thing. It is a myriad of possible relationships. And none of these relationships are necessarily wrong; most of them aren't even necessarily bad code. They're simply implicit relationships between types.

The Library Fundamentals v1 includes `observer_ptr<T>`, which is just a pointer wrapper; it conveys no ownership semantics. However, the Core C++ Guidelines recommends that [raw pointers be used for most of these use-without-ownership relations](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-raw); instead suggesting that pointers which do own something be annotated with `owner<T>`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation
Could be that my single-line description is too simplistic.
If this is not the definition you are familiar with, could you introduce me to your concept of Aggregation please?

In relation to the question, yes, there are hundreds of aggregation situations, that is why I ask for the "correct" way. In the same way, errors are a very complex topic, but we all agree in a few ways to manage them (exceptions, error return, etc.)

I will definitively look at your observer_ptr/owner templates. Thanks

Comment: @AdrianMaire: "*there are hundreds of aggregation situations, that is why I ask for the "correct" way.*" You seem to have missed my point. Because there are hundreds of such situations, there *is no* "correct way". There can't be.